# Output location of mvn appengine:devserver_start

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm using the maven appengine plugin and starting the devserver asynchronously using `mvn appengine:devserver_start`. If you use the synchronous version `mvn appengine:devserver` the server output is printed to the console.

However when using `devserver_start` where is the server output logged to?

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to file issues on the Maven plugin itself:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin/issues
This way, it can be addressed faster.

Comment: Please follow https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin/issues/42 for updates.

Answer (score 0):

There's no logging from appengine:devserver_start in async mode.  Google recommends using `mvn appengine:devserver` if you need to examine logs.